is pre cum accepted in hinduism
I am a 19 year old....my family has always been very religious...although I  was never against hinduism...I wasn't too much into it...and I had mastrubation problems but a while back I got into a relationship and also became religious(praying to god, wearing panch mukhi rudraksh, chanting hanuman chalisa) and my habit of mastrubation faded away but every once in a while I get pre cum when me and my partner hug or etc...I am worried this will negate or render the effect of my prayer

Night fall, pre-cum etc are natural, masturbation is prohibited but that too for spiritual reasons
